# How to sort by date (asc or desc) an Observable in Angular components

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am wonder how to sort by date the data within my array in my component, I have the following structure:

**Template:**

```
<div>
  <button (click)="sortByDate()">
    Sort by date
  </button>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let rally of rallies$ | async">
    <img src="{{ rally.icon }}" />
</div>
```

**Component:**

```
rallies$: Observable<Rally>;

  constructor(private ralliesService: RalliesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRallies();
  }

  getRallies() {
    this.rallies$ = this.ralliesService.getRallies();
  }

  sortRalliesByDate() {
    ???
  }
```

The thing is that i understand how to operate with an array in component after subscribe an observable, but now I want to operate directly in the observable and work with the async pipe in the template.

Answer (score 3):

Finnaly solved in that way:

```
sortRalliesByDateDesc() {
        this.rallies$ = this.rallies$.pipe(map((rallies => rallies.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.startDate).getTime() - new Date(a.startDate).getTime()))))
}

  sortRalliesByDateAsc() {
        this.rallies$ = this.rallies$.pipe(map((rallies => rallies.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.startDate).getTime() - new Date(b.startDate).getTime()))))
}
```

**Stackblitz EXAMPLE:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glwwvv

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to sort by the property `createdAt`, you could simply map it like so:

```
sortRalliesByDate() {
  return this.rallies$
    .pipe(
      map(rallies => rallies.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt)
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it always throws the error " Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'Rally' "

Comment: @Jgascona I thought `rallies$` is an `Observablle<Rally[]`. If not, then what is it?

Comment: wow... i defined actually as ```Observablle<Rally>``` ... I think you got it

Comment: Thanks you too much, you helped me a lot to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a reference to the value that got emitted from the observable with the as operator. Then you can pass it to the sort function.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="rallies$ | async as rallies">
  <div>
    <button (click)="sortByDate(rallies)">
      Sort by date
    </button>
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let rally of rallies">
      <img src="{{ rally.icon }}" />
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

and have the sort function take the template variable as a parameter.

```
sortByDate = rallies => rallies.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
```

The problem with this solution is that you are mutating the rallies that is emitted by the rallies$ observable. I use a clone pipe that clones the emitted value before assigning to the template variable.

```
*ngIf="rallies$ | async | clone as rallies"
```

This way the sort function does not cause any side effects.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { clone } from './clone';

@Pipe({
  name: 'clone'
})
export class ClonePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
    return clone(value);
  }
}
```

and the clone function

```
export const clone = (obj: any) =>
  Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.map(item => clone(item))
    : obj instanceof Date
    ? new Date(obj.getTime())
    : obj && typeof obj === 'object'
    ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((o, prop) => {
        o[prop] = clone(obj[prop]);
        return o;
      }, {})
    : obj;
```

The cloning means that we did not cause any side effect with other components that may be using the data from the rallies$ observable.